# Pointers and Dereference Operator

Tags: c

*a = *b
In C, the above expression is always interpreted as the assignment of the value at the address contained in b to the value at an address in a.
But, according to the precedence of operators and associativity rule, * has higher priority than the assignment operator '=', and is associative from right to left.
If we interpret the given expression keeping in mind these rules, it should be interpreted as:

> *a=*b
>
> (*a)=(*b)
>
> 10=20(Supposing *a=10 & *b=20)

So, this must result in an error if taken as per the rules of precedence and also as per the rule that there can't be an expression on the left-hand side of an assignment operator. Then why does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is in topic here.

Anyway, `(*a)` in `(*a)=(*b)` denotes a [lvalue](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4) referring to the object in `a`.
On the right side of the assignment, `(*b)` also denotes an lvalue, but this lvalue undergoes [lvalue conversion](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2) and is converted to the actual value stored in the object pointed by $b$ (i.e., to 20).

In the end, the value 20 is assigned to the object pointed by `a`.

See, for example, [this discussion](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-in-a/059600298X/ch03s01.html) about lvalues and rvalues.

Comment: Got it...thank you so much.